# is there a way to disconnect the eyes from a mesh to become a separate object?

Tags: modeling

is there a way to disconnect the eyes from a mesh to become a separate object?

I've imported many sfmlab models that look great but the eyes are part of the mesh and using a addon
I got called AutoRigPro, it needs the eyes to be disconnected in order to rig the model. Is there a way
maybe in edit mode or something to disconnect them from the main model? I'm pretty new to blender btw.

Comment: Select everything you want to separate (in edit mode), then press P (separate) and pick "by selection". The two will now be separate objects.

Comment: thanks this fixed my problem!